# sort array of dictionaries to make members of different group to be adjacent

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

How to create maximum possible pair of random users from array of objects such that user in pair are from different teams.

```
users = [
{"name" : "mike", "team" : "sales"},
{"name" : "sara", "team" : "sales"},
{"name" : "tom", "team" : "sales"},
{"name" : "piku", "team" : "admin"},
{"name" : "cante", "team" : "engg"},
{"name": "jeff", "team": "engg"},
{"name": "roy", "team": "marketing"},
{"name": "lee", "team": "dev"},
{"name": "anil", "team": "dev"},
{"name": "james", "team": "dev"}
]

result = [("mike", "lee"), ("sara", "anil"), ("tom", "james"), ("piku", "cante"), ("jeff", "roy")]
```

I have tried with below code, assuming the array of the users are sorted already, such that no adjacent user are from same team. Question is how to sort the input array to make user of different team as adjacent such that maximum possible pair can be formed.

```
   def getRandomPair(users):
      #users = sorted(users, key=lambda i: i['team'])
      result, pair = [], []
      for user in users:
          pair.append(user["name"])
          if len(pair) == 2:
              result.append(pair)
              pair = []
      return result
```

Comment: IMO this is not a _sorting_ but a _matching_ problem, therefore you'll need a _graph_ or _network_ library  like e.g. [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/#).

Comment: @SpghttCd - I need to get the answer without using a package. any idea how would you implemnnt this?

Comment: Make a dictionary of different teams. Use defaultdict(list) for it. Now you will have different lists with people belonging to same team. So just join different different elements from lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let `v` be an array of your guys.
given `s:v->{int,S}` a function which upon `v` returns the maximum number of valid pairs found in `v` and `S` an array of the actual pairs found

you may then implement s like

```
def s(v):
    g_best = {'size':0, 'S':[[]]}
    for every valid pair as p in v:
        v_recurse = v.copy().without(p)
        result = s(v_recurse)
        best = 1 + result['size']
        if best > g_best['size']:
            g_best = {
                'size':1+g_best['size']
                'S': [p] + g_best['S']
            }
        end
    end
    return g_best
```

which gives something along those lines

```
users = [
    {"name" : "mike", "team" : "sales"},
    {"name" : "sara", "team" : "sales"},
    {"name" : "tom", "team" : "sales"},
    {"name" : "piku", "team" : "admin"},
    {"name" : "cante", "team" : "engg"},
    {"name": "jeff", "team": "engg"},
    {"name": "roy", "team": "marketing"},
    {"name": "lee", "team": "dev"},
    {"name": "anil", "team": "dev"},
    {"name": "james", "team": "dev"}
]
def s(v):
    valid_pairs = []
    for ai in range(0, len(v)):
        for bi in range(ai+1, len(v)):
            [a,b] = [v[ai], v[bi]]
            if a == b or a['team'] == b['team']:
                break
            valid_pairs.append([a,b])
    g_best = {'size':0, 'S':[[]]}
    for p in valid_pairs:

        v_recurse = list(filter(lambda guy: guy not in p, v))
        result = s(v_recurse)
        cur_size = 1 + result['size']
        if cur_size > g_best['size']:
            g_best = {
                'size':1+result['size'],
                'S': [p] + result['S']
            }
    return g_best
print('result', s(users)['S'])
#result [[{'name': 'tom', 'team': 'sales'}, {'name': 'piku', 'team': 'admin'}], [{'name': 'sara', 'team': 'sales'}, {'name': 'cante', 'team': 'engg'}], [{'name': 'mike', 'team': 'sales'}, {'name': 'lee', 'team': 'dev'}], [{'name': 'jeff', 'team': 'engg'}, {'name': 'anil', 'team': 'dev'}], [{'name': 'roy', 'team': 'marketing'}, {'name': 'james', 'team': 'dev'}], []]
```

Note that you can optimize this algorithm by memoizing or taking the dynamic programming approach, but it is off topic I guess?

Answer (score 1):

The combinations from itertools gives you exactly what it says, distinct combinations.
I've made a list from your data as input parameter:

```
    users = [
    ["mike","sales"],
    ["sara","sales"],
    ["tom","sales"],
    ["piku","admin"],
    ["cante","engg"],
    ["jeff","engg"],
    ["roy","marketing"],
    ["lee","dev"],
    ["anil","dev"],
    ["james","dev"]
    ]
```

You can try the following code:

```
    pairs  = [] # empty list
    pairs = list(itertools.combinations(users,2)) #group of two

    for i in range(len(pairs)):
        person1 = (pairs[i][0][0])
        team1   = (pairs[i][0][1])
        person2 = (pairs[i][1][0])  
        team2   = (pairs[i][1][1])
        if (team1 != team2):
            print(person1,person2)
```

The output is:

```
        mike piku
        mike cante
        mike jeff
        mike roy
        mike lee
        mike anil
        mike james
        sara piku
        sara cante
        sara jeff
        sara roy
        sara lee
        sara anil
        sara james
        tom piku
        tom cante
        tom jeff
        tom roy
        tom lee
        tom anil
        tom james
        piku cante
        piku jeff
        piku roy
        piku lee
        piku anil
        piku james
        cante roy
        cante lee
        cante anil
        cante james
        jeff roy
        jeff lee
        jeff anil
        jeff james
        roy lee
        roy anil
        roy james
```